# To replace part of the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I have following URLs:

```
.../taxonomy/term/206/all/feed .../taxonomy/term/206/all
```

It is needed a RewriteRule to replace all with '0', i.e.

```
.../taxonomy/term/206/0/feed .../taxonomy/term/206/0
```

PS. 206 - just a sample, could be any number instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/all(/|.*)$ /$1/0$2 [L]
```

Note that this will take `/123/all/all/all` and rewrite it to `/123/0/0/0`

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I will try to use taxonomy/term/(numbers) for limitation.